# Why is there a difference in the output if redirected to a text file and how to solve it

Tags: c, linux

If compiled this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("If I had more time, \n");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "I would have written you a shorter letter.\n", 43);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
```

it prints on the terminal:
"If I had more time,
I would have written you a shorter letter."
In this specific order,
but when directing it to a text file (ie: ./program.a>test.txt)
the order of these 2 sentences switch, I've tried googling it but to no avail.
Any ideas

Comment: The answer is probably output buffering, specifically line buffering for the `printf` call. Explicitly flushing the output buffer after the `printf` using `fflush` should solve this.

Comment: What does your web research on buffering reveal? What did you learn, and why does it not answer your question?

Comment: Don't mix stdio and low level syscalls for i/o to the same underlying file descriptor.